# Excel - get the max value for every 15 mins in a full day data set

Tags: excel, database, excel-formula, formula, analytics

I have a set of data like this:

| Column A | Column B |
| --- | --- |
| 00:25:00 | 22 |
| 00:37:00 | 55 |
| 00:48:00 | 15 |
| 01:10:00 | 23 |
| 01:25:00 | 84 |
| 01:37:00 | 66 |
| 01:57:00 | 33 |
| 02:37:00 | 82 |
| 02:45:00 | 15 |
| 02:55:00 | 22 |
| 03:05:00 | 84 |
| 03:17:00 | 13 |
| 03:25:00 | 55 |
| 03:37:00 | 22 |
| 03:45:00 | 10 |
| 03:57:00 | 05 |

I need to find a way to get the max value in Column B for a 15mins timeframe from column A.
Basically, I need to answer the question "For every 15mins, what is the max value obtainable in that hour?" and I need to do that for the whole day.

Since I have at least 1 year of data for each day of the month and for each hour of that day, I need to find a way to quickly solve this. Please note that, as you can see from Column A, the timeframe is irregular.

I tried with Pivot Table but did not really helped me

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using a Pivot Table. But, instead of using your times as shown (and I assume there are dates in your actual data), you need to create a new column which has your 15-minute bins.

The formula for the new column:

```
=FLOOR(A2,TIME(0,15,0))
```

or, if you have the later versions of Excel, you can reference the entire Column A range and the results will spill down.

```
=FLOOR(A2:A17,TIME(0,15,0))
```

Then merely use that column as your time column in the Pivot table instead of the original.

[image]

***Edit:** Add details of how to construct pivot table*

For the Pivot Table:

- Select the `Column B` and `Bin` ranges
- Insert => Pivot Table
- Drag `Bin` to the Rows area

  - If Excel expands the `Bin` into various time segments, merely remove them.
- Drag `Column B` to the Values area.

  - From the drop-down arrow on the Values

    - Value Field Settings

      - Select Max
      - Custom Name: As you wish

Comment: when I do this, it replicates some time data. For example, if between 0:00 and 0:15  I have 0:07 and 0:09, it give me twice 0:10.

Comment: As you can see from the screen shot, that doesn't happen in the Pivot Table. Without data that replicates your problem, I cannot tell what's going on. And I have no idea what you mean by `twice 0:10`

Comment: @Pliz89 In your example that you posted as an answer, you show exactly what is expected from the helper column I recommended. But you don't show what happened when you created the **Pivot table**.

Comment: @Pliz89 Are you having a problem with the Pivot Table?

Answer (score 0):

Just copy, paste, and update your ranges for time and values below:

```
=LET(
    time, B3:B19,
    values, C3:C19,
    t, SEQUENCE(ROUNDUP(MAX(time) / (1 / 96) + 1, 0), , 0, 1 / 96),
    HSTACK(
        TEXT(t, "h:mm:ss"),
        MAP(t, LAMBDA(m, MAXIFS(values, time, "<=" & m, time, ">" & m - 1 / 96)))
    )
)
```

[image]